# So I'm trying to call the array and pas the login information through the If function but it keeps coming up with an error

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So what I'm trying to do is search through the array of employee login information to check if the information entered into the text box matches it. If so, close the current form and open the Roster Form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim employee(2) As Boolean
    
    employee(0) = txtUsername.Text = "Admin" And txtPassword.Text = "AdminPass"
    employee(1) = txtUsername.Text = "User" And txtPassword.Text = "UserPass"

    'If informaiton is correct, open roster and close login      
    If txtUsername.Text And txtPassword.Text = employee(0 Or 1) Then
        Roster.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        'If informaiton is incorrect, message box will open
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Either Username or Password is incorrect."))
    End If      
End Sub
```

Comment: Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question. It's good that you posted the relevant code but it's all downhill from there. Firstly, a question that contains nothing but code is not a question. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question, which means exactly what you're trying to achieve, exactly how you're trying to achieve it and exactly what happens when you try. What happens doesn't "it doesn't work" or "there's an error". It means EXACTLY what and where. When the question is complete, THEN write a title to summarise.

Comment: One of the reasons that it's important that you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve is that we shouldn't have to work that out from code that doesn't do it. That `If` statement is obviously nonsense but, unless you explain what it's actually supposed to do, we can't tell you what it should look like. Keep in mind that your array contains `Boolean` values that indicate whether the inputs match valid combinations. Ignoring the fact that that's bizarre to begin with, what's the logical next step? Surely just to check whether any element is `True`, because that's what indicates success.

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you very much for your explanation, I'm new to this and still just learning so appreciate you taking the time to tell me! 
I'll rephrase my question an be more particular about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim employee(2) As Boolean
```

This declares and array of 3 elements with indexes 0, 1, 2. Then you add values to the elements based on the input of 2 text boxes. If I type Admin in `TextBox1` and AdminPass in `TextBox2` your array values are `True`, `False`, `False`. The third element is `False` because it was never assigned a value and `Boolean` is a value type with a default value of `False`.

Your `If` statement is not correct. An `If` statement with an And expects 2 statements that evaluate to `Boolean`. The `.Text` in a `TextBox` is a `String` not a `Boolean`. Remember your array only contains 3 elements that are `True`, `False`, `False`. Doesn't make any sense.

I am guessing you want to compare what the user types in to a list of accepted user names and passwords. I made a `Class` to represent this. I added a parameterized `Sub New` so it would be easy to add new employees. I overrode `.ToString` so we would have an easy way to compare.

In the `Button.Click` you create a list of employees and add the employees to the list. Now you can loop through the list and when you find a match show the next form. If the loop completes without a match the failure message box is shown.

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Sub New(uName As String, pWord As String)
        UserName = uName
        Password = pWord
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{UserName},{Password}"
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of Employee)
    lst.Add(New Employee("Admin", "AdminPass"))
    lst.Add(New Employee("User", "UserPass"))
    For Each emp As Employee In lst
        If $"{TextBox1.Text},{TextBox2.Text}" = emp.ToString Then
            Form2.Show()
            'Roster.Show()
            Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Either Username or Password is incorrect.")
End Sub
```

This is only one approach. There are many ways to accomplish this.